# why eclipse does not automatically resolve all includes in C as it does in java?

Tags: c, eclipse

i am trying to fix my eclipse IDE for C, so that it should resolve all include issues automatically as it does in java (import). I have included my compiler include directory under
**project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->GNU C** and then under includes tab I included directory **C:\MinGW\include** but it still does not work.

Am I doing something wrong ? any suggestion how to sresolve this issue.

Comment: AFAIK Java does not use the C/C++ preprocessor

Comment: So you mean we cant resolve includes automatically in eclipse? We have to manually add #include<stdio.h> and so on ?

Comment: I never use Eclipse (Emacs is good enough for me), but pre-processor directives like `#include<stdio.h>` are part of the C99 language, and I would not have them added automatically by the editor. If C does not make you happy, use some other language (Common Lisp, Ocaml, Haskell, C++....). However, you'll need to configure your IDE to pass appropriate `-I`... & `-L`... & `-l`... flags to `gcc`. Remember that order of options for `gcc` matters a lot. Don't forget `-Wall  -Wextra -g`

Comment: Did I said that C does not make me happy? save your suggestions for someone else. I will find a way or someone will help me out :) anyways thanks for your time. And by da way I have already set those flags in IDE GCC setting.

Comment: This is a valid question. If you dont know the answer you are not supposed to degrade it.

Comment: My point is that you should not expect a tool to reliably guess which `#include` you need -because two different libraries might e.g. have some similar API. C is not Java, the preprocessor is practically essential (even if in principle you could avoid it by copy & pasting)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your query correctly. Please validate my paraphrasing of your question. Suppose you have written a C program like _int main() { puts("Welcome to C"); }_, you want the Eclipse editor to prepend the line **#include <stdio.h>** to your code, right?